Frutiger or universalis fonts in textual and mathematical mode
I would reproduce my TikZ/pgfplots graphs using Frutiger fonts in both text mode and math mode. In CTAN the Frutiger fonts are avaliables here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/truetypemetrics.
I have seen that since 2022 exist a clone of Frutiger fonts named Universalis (website: https://ctan.org/pkg/universalis). This package Universalis provides LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX support for the UniversalisADFStd family of fonts, designed by Hirwin Harendal. The font is suitable as an alternative to fonts such as Adrian Frutiger's Univers and Frutiger.*
I am not able to use the Frutiger fonts available in CTAN (I would to know how they work). I know, instead, to use the fonts universalis. See the MWE below:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{universalis}

\begin{document}
Text mode 2, \textbf{2/3}
\end{document}



Is there a mathematical package that can be adapted to these fonts (frutiger or universalis) available in CTAN similar to this image below?


I hope that somebody

Frutiger is a commercial font from LinoType, you can purchase it here: https://www.myfonts.com/collections/frutiger-tr-font-linotype

There is a .zip file at the package level: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/truetypemetrics/
